# mysql several column ranking per group

Tags: mysql

I have table data in this format

```
studno  name    level   year   term  subject1  subject2  subject3 
212    victor     l1    2000    1      45        56        80
213     HOM       l1    2000    1      42        56        70
214     ken       l1    2000    1      60        70        50
215    ted        l1    2000    1      46        36        47
212    victor     l1    2000    2      45        36        68
213    Hom        l1    2000    2      38        78        49
214    ken        l1    2000    2      38        34        62
```

my desired output is the following

```
studno  name    level   year   term  subject1 sub1rank subject2  sub2rank 
213    victor     l1    2000    1      42        3       56        2 
214    HOM        l1    2000    1      60        1       70        1 
215    TED        l1    2000    1      46        2        36       3 
212   victor      l1    2000    2      45      2           36      1  
213    hOM        l1    2000    2      38      3           36      1  
214    KEN        l1    2000    2      38      3           32      3  
215    TED        l1    2000    2      90      1           30      4
```

I have managed to get the rank  but the problem is how to get the rank per year, level, term and subject. another problem is that if i use nested statement and try to create view in mysql database it throws an error, "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing your code.  But MySQL does not allow subqueries in views, so you can create a separate view containing the subquery and then join on the view

Comment: THIS WHAT I HAD DONE SET @SB1=1; SET @SB2=1; SET @PREV_SUB1=NULL; SET @PREV_SUB2=NULL; create view viewss as SELECT STUDNO,NAME,LEVEL,YEAR,TERM,SUB1,SUB1RANK,SUB2,SUB2RANK FROM ( SELECT *, @SB1:=IF(@PREV_SUB1!=SUB1,@SB1+1,@SB1) AS SUB2RANK,@PREV_SUB1:=SB1 FROM ( SELECT STUDENTNUMBER,fullnames,stream,ACADEMICYEAR,TERMCODE,ACADLEVELCODE,@SB2:=IF(@PREV_SUB2!=ENG,@SUB2+1,@SB2) AS SUB2RANK,@PREV_SUB2:=SB2,SUB1,SUB2 FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY SUB2 DESC )E1 ORDER BY SUB1 DESC )M1

Comment: the subquery in your `FROM` clause, needs to join in a separate view and then join to it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with correlated subqueries in the `select` clause.  If I understand correctly, something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (select COUNT(distinct t1.subject1)
        from t t2
        where t2.level = t.level and t2.year = t.year and t2.term = t.term and
              t2.subject1 >= t.subject1
       ) as subj1rank,
       (select COUNT(distinct t2.subject2)
        from t t2
        where t2.level = t.level and t2.year = t.year and t2.term = t.term and
              t2.subject2 >= t.subject2
       ) as subj2rank
from t
```

The `count(*)` might be `count(distinct subject1)` (etc.), depending on how you treat ties.

Comment: Gordon I followed you sample query abouve and managed to execute bt the problem am getting is as follows <pre>studid name clevel term eng kisw maths subj1rank subj2rank
987 muy lv01 2 76 31 35 7 24
674 yed lv01 1 49 26 35 7 24
543 jack lv01 1 56 26 75 7 24
453 hei lv01 1 36 66 75 7 24
341 reds lv01 2 87 34 75 7 24
265 mal lv01 2 54 34 54 7 24
253 mark lv01 1 64 45 80 7 24
213 victor lv01 1 56 45 30 7 24
</pre>

Comment: @user1989497 . . . The issue is what is being counted.  I think you want  the `count(distinct subject1)` version for what is called a `dense_rank()` in other databases.

Comment: this is my query as for now select k.studid, k.name,k.clevel,k.term,k.subject1,
(select  count(distinct subject1)
from testrank tt 
join testrank k on k.subject1 <= tt.subject1
)subject1rank,
k.subject2, 
(select  count(distinct subject2)
from testrank tt 
join testrank k on k.subject2 <= tt.subject2
)subject2rank
 from testrank k
group by k.studid, k.name,k.clevel this is what have come up with but am not getting the ranking. its just repeating one number in all rows. Kindly assist me on where am going wrong

Comment: @user1989497 . . . You have a join in the subquery.  You need to do a correlated subquery in the `where` clause, not the `on` clause.